# ActionBar + Tab crashes when screen orientation changes

Tags: tabs, orientation, android-actionbar, landscape, portrait

My app has the following characteristics.

- When in landscape mode, split the screen in half and show a couple of Fragments ("LocFragment" and "MapFragment").
- When in portrait mode, show 2 Tabs in ActionBar. A Fragment covers the whole screen, and switch between the Fragments with Tab selection.
- Targeting 4.x+, so I'm not concerned about Support Library or ActionBarSherlock.

If the phone is in the landscape mode when the app starts, everything works fine. But the app crashes when 1) the phone is in the portrait mode, 2) app starts, and 3) the phone turned to the landscape mode.

```
layour/activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
```

```
 layout-land/activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:name="org.solamour.eq.LocFragment"
        android:id="@+id/EarthquakeListFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment
        android:name="org.solamour.eq.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/EarthquakeMapFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TabListener<LocFragment> locTabListener;
    TabListener<MapFragment> mapTabListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer);
        boolean bLandscape = fragmentContainer == null;

        if (!bLandscape) {
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            Tab listTab = actionBar.newTab();
            locTabListener = new TabListener<LocFragment>
                (this, R.id.FragmentContainer,
                        LocFragment.class);
            listTab.setText("List")
                .setContentDescription("List of locations")
                .setTabListener(locTabListener);
            actionBar.addTab(listTab);

            Tab mapTab = actionBar.newTab();
            mapTabListener = new TabListener<MapFragment>
                (this, R.id.FragmentContainer,
                        MapFragment.class);
            mapTab.setText("Map")
                .setContentDescription("Map of interests")
                .setTabListener(mapTabListener);
            actionBar.addTab(mapTab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer);
        boolean bLandscape = fragmentContainer == null;

        if (!bLandscape) {
            FragmentTransaction ft =
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mapTabListener.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mapTabListener.fragment);
            }
            if (locTabListener.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(locTabListener.fragment);
            }
            ft.commit();
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer);
        boolean bLandscape = fragmentContainer == null;

        if (!bLandscape) {
            locTabListener.fragment =getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentByTag(LocFragment.class.getName());
            mapTabListener.fragment = getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentByTag(MapFragment.class.getName());
        }
    }

    public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment>
            implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment fragment;
        private Activity activity;
        private Class<T> fragmentClass;
        private int fragmentContainer;

        public TabListener(Activity activity,
                int fragmentContainer, Class<T> fragmentClass) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.fragmentContainer = fragmentContainer;
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (fragment == null) {
                String fragmentName = fragmentClass.getName();
                fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentName);
                ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentName);
            } else {
                ft.attach(fragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(fragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (fragment != null)
                ft.attach(fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Speaking of crash, Eclipse simply says "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment". It must be somewhere in "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)", but I'm not sure how to set up the source to follow inside the code. I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

__

sol

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line 7 in the landscape layout:

`fragment
         android:name="org.solamour.eq.LocFragment"`

Maybe the path to the class is wrong or Maybe the LocFragment had an error and when you show it you get a crash.